# Vue.js not sending Authorization header

Tags: webpack, vue.js, jwt, axios

I have problem with Authorization header in Vue.js 2 using vue-resource and axios(with both is the same problem). Vue not adding header when send request to backend. Below is my code and example request. Server is running on WSGIServer and its Django(is not nginx yet).

**When request send:**

Access-Control-Request-Headers: "authorization,xxxxx"

**Instead of:**

Authorization: "JWT "

Backend works fine - I used CURL to check request and response.

**Accounts.vue:**

```
<script>
  import Account from './Account.vue';
  import axios from 'axios';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        accounts: []
      }
    },
    created: function () {
      this.getAccounts();
    },
    methods: {
      getAccounts() {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

        axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000';
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'JWT <my_token>';

        axios.get('/api/accounts/')
          .then(
            response => {
              this.accounts = response.data;
            }
          )
          .catch(
            error => console.log(error)
          );

      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

**General**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/api/accounts/
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:localhost:8000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Response Headers**

```
Allow:GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length:58
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Wed, 21 Jun 2017 06:59:34 GMT
Server:WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.2
Vary:Accept, Cookie
WWW-Authenticate:JWT realm="api"
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization,xxxxxx
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8000
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/accounts
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/58.0.3029.110 Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Do you have a single server which servers both web pages and API? Or two different services?

Comment: two different servers one with API is localhost:8000 and second(front end) is localhost:8080

Comment: Also shouldn't the header have the following format: **Authorization: Bearer <token>** according to: https://jwt.io/introduction/ section *How do JSON Web Tokens work?*

Comment: Yes this is default JWT format but I changed "Bearer" to "JWT" <token> in my backend.

Comment: Presently you are setting up headers two times, consider simplifying the code and leaving only one place where you set up the header.

Comment: This line of code looks strange: `xxxxx: 'JWT <my_token>'`, it should be more like this: `Authorization: 'JWT <my_token>'`

Comment: When i use one of them problem is the same I leave the second one with xxxx only for example that here is problem too.

Comment: Probably the problem arises from the fact that your frontend and API are on different ports and the browser has to deal with CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS `Access-Control-Request-Headers` and `Access-Control-Request-Method` are headers in preflight requests made by browser. Do you have CORS set up on your API server?

Comment: I thought problem is on frontend because CURL worked fine but problem was with server. I don't know why because always works in this configuration. Problem was with CORS on my backend and i used [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) to resolve problems with headers. Thanks for help @vsenko